# javascript array save to database in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a user created array which is displayed by a function in a table (this is all done with jquery on the client side). I want to save this to the database so it can be linked to and displayed again.
I have my rails model and form setup to accept a string (presumably I must convert  the array to a string) but I'm entirely unsure how to code this properly.
I've followed [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/)
  tutorial but I'm not sure where it's going wrong.
I don't need an exact answer, just looking to be pointed in the right direction..

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript

```js
var arrayAsString = JSON.stringify(myArray);
sendToDatabaseUsingAJAX( arrayAsString );
// ... later ...
var arrayFromString = JSON.parse( arrayAsString );
```

### Ruby

```ruby
require 'json'
array_as_string = my_array.to_json
send_to_database( array_as_string )
# ... later ...
array_from_string = JSON.parse( array_as_string_gotten_from_db )
```